# Editing the accessibility tags of an existing PDF in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, tags, accessibility

I need to change some tag types in an existing PDF's accessibility tag tree. i.e I don't want to create the PDF along with the tags from scratch, just change for example a paragraph tag to an H1 tag, without changing the PDF's content.

Another option would be to create the whole tag tree, but again- for an existing PDF with content.

Some 3rd party providers I've looked at are Aspose, Syncfusion, PdfSharp, Itext and Spire. No success with any of them:

Aspose's tag types are readonly, Syncfusion's editing simply doesn't work, PdfSharp throws exceptions, and the others either have only an option to build the whole PDF from scratch, or no options at all.

Anyone know of any available solution, that works?
Thank you

Comment: If you're only changing a few tags, you can do it by hand with Adobe Acrobat.

Comment: We have noticed that you have created similar question on our dedicated forum (https://forum.aspose.com/t/changing-tags-of-a-tagged-pdf/263249) and we have also responded to it. You may please follow up there for further update. This is Asad Ali and I work as Developer Evangelist at Aspose.